# We all have it, but what is it?

Tags: riddle

> We all have it.
>   At somewhere, Long and at somewhere, short.
>   On someone, thick and on someone, thin.
>   On somewhat, gold and on somewhat, black.
>   When someone doesn't have it, and we laugh.

**What is it?**

Comment: "When someone didn't  [sic] have it"... implies that some people don't  have it. The first line is "we all have it". Contradiction.

Comment: Oh well, sorry for that. I meant we all have it naturally, but you can cut or shave to make it disappear.. or someone just have it in somewhere on him/her, not everywhere as everyone..

^_^

Comment: Should "think" be "thick" or is this a reference to being near the brain? @d'alar'cop To paraphrase someone I know, riddles are all allusion, so wrong stuff is acceptable ;-)

Comment: @randal'thor Edited ^_^ it's "Thick" actually.

Comment: @randal'thor I have been reading Pedant of the Pedant too much :p

Comment: We don't all have hair. Michael Berryman doesn't, for example.

Comment: this sounds wrong

Comment: @moopet We all have it, if someone doesn't have on his/her head, they still have on hand, legs, or underarms... there's too many places. 

& I don't know Michael Berryman :P

Comment: & sorry if my english make @Vic sounds wrong, I am not native, I just like riddles and love myself being in puzzling.

Comment: @nai We don't all have it; that's like saying we all have two legs.

Comment: Hi dear @moopet, I guess I explained well about how all people have it, so could you please explain us how people don't have it [as you said] instead of writing 'We don't all have it'. 
Because I personally never seen a person who doesn't even have a single hair.

About ur example, human being actually have two legs, with no circumstance for this eg. A human figure is composed of one head, a body, two hands and two legs.

Comment: @nai I gave you an example of someone who has no hair already. Not all people have two legs. The global average is something like 1.999 legs per person because some people are born without them or have them amputated. I'm just trying to be complete - a puzzle should be unambiguous otherwise it's unsolvable.

Comment: @moopet Yep, I know what you are trying to say, I just don't want to admit it because what you wrote above is a conditional thing, a circumstance, not general. Without concerning to my puzzle, I don't think I should say we all don't have hair or don't have two legs. That's all. I want it to be general.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Hair

Although

> Laughing at bald people isn't very nice :P

We all have it.

> Everyone (or at least the vast majority) has hair somewhere

At somewhere, Long and at somewhere, short.

> Some people have long hair, some have short. Also, head hair tends to be longer than, say, eyebrow hair

On someone, thick and on someone, thin.

> Some people have thick hair, some have thin

On somewhat, gold and on somewhat, black.

> Different people have different hair colours

When someone doesn't have it, and we laugh.

> Again, laughing at bald people isn't nice. **finds bigger hat**

Comment: It is just fun ^_^ .. You know, then we give a nickname for him/her :P

Comment: I thought this answer would be to simple :P

Comment: Ah, now we know why you have a hat.

Comment: The more important question is whether I have a black hat or a white hat, but I need at least two more logicians to solve that. Also, increasingly yes :(

Comment: This answer doesn't have an explanation either (though it is easy to see it is correct).

Comment: @kaine The riddle is more easily solved as a whole than line-by-line, but I've added an explanation anyway