# We all have it. What is it?

Tags: riddle

**We all have it**

> Some are long, some are short.
>
> Some colored, some natural.
>
> Some filthy, some clean.

**What is it?**

Comment: Should be fairly easy.

Comment: You should probably change the title to distinguish this riddle from http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15855/we-all-have-it-but-what-is-it

Comment: To the close-voters: admittedly the titles are extremely similar, but the riddles are not the same and the answers are different. I've voted to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not hair, then:

> Fingernails

Answer (score 2):

I think it might be

> Hair

again :P

Comment: Nope!, I wanna say you're close.. but there isn't any hair nearby!

Answer (score 2):

Could be

> rope.

*Some are long, some are short.*

> How long is a piece of string?

*Some colored, some natural.*

> Coloured ropes and those made of natural fibre.

*Some filthy, some clean.*

> Ropes used for mooring a ship are usually filthy, but rope can also be clean.

I think the riddle is "too broad". Hair also fits, as @PirateSoul said.

Comment: Yeah I guess you're right about it being too broad. Be nice, It's my first time 'puzzling' :)

Comment: @Paramone Sorry, didn't mean to be rude! I normally do make an effort to be nice to new users. Welcome to the site btw :-)

Comment: not a problem at all, I'm used to Stackexchange, but just 'discovered' the puzzling section. I'm usually on Android or Stack Overflow :), Thank you tho!